# Cmap Tools - which file to execute

Tags: executable

I have installed CMapTools in Ubuntu, into a directory ~IHMCP CMap Tools.  But I can't seem to figure out which is the executable file.  Can you help?
Thanks!

Comment: Where we can download CMapTools (to help you find executables)?

Answer (score 0):

In the directory where you installed cmap, there is a script called `CmapTools` that you just need to launch like any other script:

```
$ ./CmapTools
```